# How to parse SDP_TYPE_SEQUENCE in C++ code running as a Bluetooth client on Windows communicating with an Android device?

Tags: c++, winapi, bluetooth

Using Bluetooth socket programming on Windows.

I am calling the Win32 `BluetoothSdpEnumAttributes()` API. The callback function (`PFN_BLUETOOTH_ENUM_ATTRIBUTES_CALLBACK pfnCallback`) is then calling the Win32 `BluetoothSdpGetElementData()` API.

I can see the following attributes coming back from the services from the Android device:

- `ServiceClassIds` (0x1)
- `ProtocolDescriptorList` (0x4)
- `BrowseGroupList` (0x5)
- `BluetoothProfileDescriptorList` (0x9)
- `AdditionalProtocolDescriptorList` (0xD)

All of these attributes are of type `SDP_TYPE_SEQUENCE` (0x6).

Based on the attribute name, can I assume that they are all one or more Bluetooth UUIDs (GUIDS on Windows)?

If yes, I think the code below will get the list of UUIDs into memory.

```cpp
    case SDP_TYPE_SEQUENCE: {
        ULONG l_ULONGSequenceLength = SDP_ELEMENT_DATA_in.data.sequence.length + 1;
        BYTE* l_pBYTESequence = new BYTE[l_ULONGSequenceLength];
        ZeroMemory(l_pBYTESequence, l_ULONGSequenceLength);
        memcpy(l_pBYTESequence,
               SDP_ELEMENT_DATA_in.data.sequence.value,
               SDP_ELEMENT_DATA_in.data.sequence.length);

        // TODO: handle the memory

        delete[] l_pBYTESequence;
        break;
    }
```

I can see that there are helper functions (specifically [`PRETRIEVEUUID128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthsdpddi/nc-bthsdpddi-pretrieveuuid128)) for Bluetooth device driver programming in [`<bthsdpddi.h>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthsdpddi/), but our code is running in user mode.

I took a stab at getting `<bthsdpddi.h>` into our current code, but was not successful.

Does anyone have any sample code on how to parse the `SDP_TYPE_SEQUENCE` memory?

OK, the way to iterate/loop over the bluetooth sequence data is to use the Win32 API named BluetoothSdpGetContainerElementData (see code snippet below).

```
    case SDP_TYPE_SEQUENCE: {
        HBLUETOOTH_CONTAINER_ELEMENT l_HBLUETOOTH_CONTAINER_ELEMENT = NULL;
        SDP_ELEMENT_DATA l_SDP_ELEMENT_DATA;
        DWORD l_DWORD =
            BluetoothSdpGetContainerElementData(
                SDP_ELEMENT_DATA_in.data.sequence.value,
                SDP_ELEMENT_DATA_in.data.sequence.length,
                &l_HBLUETOOTH_CONTAINER_ELEMENT,
                &l_SDP_ELEMENT_DATA);
        while (l_DWORD == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            // recursive method call...
            const _variant_t l_variant_t =
                ConvertAttributeToVariant(
                    ULONGAttributeId_in,
                    pTCHARAttributeName_in,
                    l_SDP_ELEMENT_DATA);

            l_DWORD =
                BluetoothSdpGetContainerElementData(
                    SDP_ELEMENT_DATA_in.data.sequence.value,
                    SDP_ELEMENT_DATA_in.data.sequence.length,
                    &l_HBLUETOOTH_CONTAINER_ELEMENT,
                    &l_SDP_ELEMENT_DATA);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Unelated: Save yourself the trouble of having to "handle memory" and use `std::vector`.

Comment: Each attribute's data differ depending on the attribute. You cannot assume they're all guids, they are not. Check out Bluetooth Core Specification https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-3/ page 1202 . PS: you can also use WinRT to get all this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.sdprecords (but it won't parse each attribute, it's still a raw buffer)